# Construction xml file: This document already has a ' DocumentElement ' node

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I am trying to construct a .xml file of the form

```
<Orders>
    <Id type="System.Int32">1</Id>
    <OrderItems>
        <OrderItem>
            <Id type="System.Int32">321</Id>
            <Product type="System.String">Coffee</Product>
        </OrderItem>
    </OrderItems>
    <Client type="System.String">Johnny</Client>
<Orders>
```

For `Order` model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Products { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
}
```

Here, I create the `Order` element

```
public void SaveToFile(IEnumerable<Order> elementsList)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration xmlDec = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", string.Empty);
        xmlDoc.PrependChild(xmlDec);
        XmlElement elemRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Orders");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(elemRoot);
        XmlHelper<Order> xmlHelper = new XmlHelper<Order>();
        foreach (var order in _orders)
        {
            xmlHelper.AddNodeToXmlDocument(xmlDoc, elemRoot, order);
        }
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.Save(_filePath);
    }
```

And here, I am trying to construct the sub-elements. It works fine for Id and Client, but when I try to create the order items, I get this error at line `document.AppendChild(elemRoot);`

```
public void AddNodeToXmlDocument(XmlDocument document, XmlElement rootElement, object myObject)
    {
        XmlElement myObjectElement = document.CreateElement(EntityFormatter.GetObjectName(myObject));
        foreach (var objectProperty in EntityFormatter.GetPropertiesAndValues(myObject))
        {
           if ((objectProperty.Value.GetType().FullName).ToString().Contains("System.Collections.Generic.List"))
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"Models[.][A-Za-z]+");
                Match match = regex.Match(objectProperty.Value.ToString());
                var elemRoot = document.CreateElement(match.Value.Substring(7));
                document.AppendChild(elemRoot);
                foreach (var obj in objectProperty.Value.ToString())
                {
                    AddNodeToXmlDocument(document, elemRoot, obj);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var elem = document.CreateElement(objectProperty.Key);
                elem.SetAttribute("type", objectProperty.Value.GetType().FullName);
                elem.InnerText = objectProperty.Value.ToString();
                myObjectElement.AppendChild(elem);
            }
        }
        rootElement.AppendChild(myObjectElement);
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using *XmlSerialization* instaed of writing coed to create the xml file?

Comment: Because it is a homework and we are not allowed to use serialization

Answer (score 0):

XML specification only allows *single root element* in a document. `document.AppendChild(elemRoot)` line in your `AddNodeToXmlDocument()` method throws exception because root element has been created before in the `SaveToFile()` method :

```
.....
XmlElement elemRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Orders");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(elemRoot);
.....
```

It isn't clear what you're trying to do with the erroneous line, maybe you want to append `elemRoot` to the previously created root element instead :

```
.....
var elemRoot = document.CreateElement(match.Value.Substring(7));
document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elemRoot);
.....
```

Comment: `match.Value="Model.OrderItem"` I want my element to be called `OrderItem` instead of `Model.OrderItem`. I have already tried `document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elemRoot);`, but I get the same error

Comment: That's the only possible cause of *This document already has a ' DocumentElement ' node* error that I can see from the code posted. Anyway, if you could post a simplified codes that I can easily copy-paste, run and see the error, it will be much easier to diagnose the problem